# No output from the loop

Tags: php, performance, garbage-collection

I'm iterating over a huge array and it involves querying multiple APIs so to avoid data loss and timeout, I'm doing this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  if ($i % 100 == 0) {
    echo 'processed: '.$i."\n";
    // save to file
  }
}
```

... it works if the loop is a few hundred iterations during test and outputs `processed ...`, but nothing at all in prod environment during the script is running, it echos everything only after its done. I just want to avoid any timeouts incase it takes (and usually does) long.

Comment: echo out the $count, are you actually getting 100s in prod?

Comment: How is the production enviroment different from your testing enviroment ? 
How long does it take approximately ? 
Are there any server restrictions ? 
Check your max_execution_time [Link](https://docs.oseems.com/general/application/php/increase-max-execution-time)

Comment: Yes I do, but only after the script is done processing everything. It doesn't output each `100` at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP output is buffered; see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php). If you flush the buffer (or turn buffering off), you'll see it happen in real-time.

As "belt and braces", if you really care about the output, I'd echo the $count before you even enter the loop.

Comment: Ah I see, is it a good practice to flush the buffer for these types of scripts?

Comment: Flushing the buffer obviously ties up a little resource, but if you wish to see a "real-time" (i.e. close to real-time) output, you'll need to either flush of switch buffering off. What PHP is probably doing is just saving up the output until you hit a certain amount of content and then flushing automatically (or at the end of the HTTP request processing).

Comment: In other words, don't try to do ten million echos with flushes and expect your script to perform as well as a buffered solution.

Answer (score -1):

what is the aim of this code block? 
well, until $i reaches 100, it is waste of resource anyway..
you can try:

```
if( $count > 100 ) {

    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);  // no time limit

    // $count contains at least $i times 100
    for($i = 1; $i <= $count / 100; $i++) {
        echo $i * 100;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer would not process the loop properly. The purpose of the modulo block is to echo with every 100 iterations I believe. I'm presuming here that the actual processing has been redacted from the code snippet.

Comment: @Jeff Watkins What is the purpose of the loop? And what is wrong with my  logic? pseudo programmer..